# Showing a Nav component on all routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to setup my routes so that when the user navigates to localhost:3000/, the Nav and Home are displayed. But when the user navigates to localhost:3000/something, only the Nav bar should be displayed. The Nav should be always be displayed.

Here is how I have done it in v5 and it works But I'm not sure how to do it in v6.

```js
function App () {
  return (
    <>
      <div className='title'>
        <h1>My App</h1>
      </div>
      <div className='main'>
        <Route path='/' component={Nav} />
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Here is my attempt with v6

```
function App () {
  return (
    <>
      <div className='title'>
        <h1>My App</h1>
      </div>
      <div className='main'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='*'>
            <Route element={<Nav />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Not sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples you provide are a weird practice.

Its a simple as this:

```
function App () {
  return (
      <div className='main'>
        <Nav />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Im understanding your question correctly, you want to render a `Nav` on all routes. For this you can create a "layout" component to render on "/" which renders the `Nav` component and all children routes into an `Outlet`. Specify the `Home` component as the `index` route so it renders when no other routes match.

The [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet) is a new concept in RRDv6.

> An `<Outlet>` should be used in parent route elements to render their
> child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child
> routes are rendered. If the parent route matched exactly, it will
> render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.

```
const Layout = () => (
  <div>
    <Nav />    // <-- Nav rendered for all routes
    <Outlet /> // <-- children routes rendered here
  </div>
);

function App () {
  return (
    <>
      <div className='title'>
        <h1>My App</h1>
      </div>
      <div className='main'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            ... other child routes ...
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

[image: Edit showing-a-nav-component-on-all-routes]